# jquery increment number using .each()

Tags: jquery, checkbox, increment

how do i increment id using .each() function.

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
var counter = $(this).length();
var id_bookslot = data; //<-- increment id +1
var treatment_type = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
var id_treatment = $(this).attr("class");
$.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {id_bookslot: id_bookslot,id_treatment:id_treatment,treatment_type:treatment_type});
});
```

let say, there are 3 checkboxes are checked! so the id will be incrementing until 3(1,2,3).

i forgot to mention var id_bookslot = data. `data` which is an id that i retreive from database. let say it starts with 1234. and everytime .each() generate, it will increment by 1. 1234, 1235, 1236

Comment: The "counter" value will always be 1, because `this` inside the ".each()" function will always be a single DOM element.

Comment: @Pointy: Indeed. (But he doesn't use that variable so it probably doesn't matter.)

Comment: Yes I was just noting it as, well, a note :-)

Comment: You might say he _pointed out_ something funny. Ha ha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to do a `post` for *each* checkbox, and to give an index or smoething, [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) gives you an index you can use (also, avoid writing `$(this)` repeatedly, it's wasteful):

```
$("input:checked").each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id_bookslot = data + index + 1;          // <== Using the index here
  var treatment_type = $this.closest("div").attr("id");
  var id_treatment = $this.attr("class");
  $.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {
      id_bookslot:    id_bookslot,
      id_treatment:   id_treatment,
      treatment_type: treatment_type
    }
  );
});
```

Also note that `$(this).length` will always be `1`, but you weren't using your `counter` variable anyway, so I just removed it. If you use it but just didn't quote the code that is, do this:

```
var checked = $("input:checked");
checked.each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var id_bookslot = data + index + 1;          // <== Using the index here
  var treatment_type = $this.closest("div").attr("id");
  var id_treatment = $this.attr("class");
  $.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {
      id_bookslot:    index,
      id_treatment:   id_treatment,
      treatment_type: treatment_type
    }
  );
});
```

...and use `checked.length` for your `counter` variable.

Comment: J: thanks alot. i forgot to mention `var id_bookslot = data`. `data` which is an id that i retreive from database. let say it starts with `1234`. and everytime .each() generate, it will increment by 1. 1234, 1235, 1236

Comment: If that truly is an index id, then it may be better to be handled by the php script than a client side solution. You could get concurrency issues with multiple instances of the web page open.

Comment: @boyee: Updated to use `data`, and since `index` will start at `0`, I add one to it as well. Note what @MacAnthony says, though, unique IDs are best doled out by the data store, not the client browser. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method allows you to use the index of the element. That's likely the best way to accomplish this.

```
$("input:checked").each(function( index ){
    var id_bookslot = index + 1; //<-- increment id +1
    var treatment_type = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
    var id_treatment = $(this).attr("class");
    $.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {id_bookslot: id_bookslot,id_treatment:id_treatment,treatment_type:treatment_type});
});
```

I added +1 since the index is a 0 index and you seem to want it to start at 1.

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice what they were doing with counter since it wasn't a part of the immediate issue.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to move the variable outside the closure:

```
var id_bookslot = 0;

$('input:checked').each(function(){
    id_bookslot++;
    // The rest of your code
});
```

While this may work, it always seems a bit hack-y to me. You might want to think about another cleaner way to accomplish your goal (like using a traditional for loop so you have the current index available to you).

Comment: thanks. i tried your code. `var id_bookslot =data, id_bookslot++ or ++id_bookslot'. `data` is an id from database. says `1234` then increment by 1. but seems the above code instead insert `1234` it inserting `1235`

Answer (score 1):

Use the closure:

```
var id_bookslot = 0;
$("input:checked").each(function() {

   id_bookslot++;

   var treatment_type = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
   var id_treatment = $(this).attr("class");

   $.post("include/get_booking.php?insert", {
     id_bookslot:    id_bookslot,
     id_treatment:   id_treatment,
     treatment_type: treatment_type
   });
});
```

Note that I removed your `count` variable, which was always 1 (`$(this)` inside the callback being the individual element in the iteration) and which was never used.